# Problema con Selenium y Safari

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hola tengo una aplicación en Python la cual tiene accede a un sitio web con la ayuda de Selenium. Tengo el siguiente código donde creo el driver:

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.implicity_wait(4)

if __name__ = '__main__':
   u = main()
```

El problema surge en el uso de Safari, ya que cada cierto tiempo sale una ventana que pregunta que sí quiero continuar con la sesión. No hay manera de que esa ventana no aparezca. No utilizo Chrome porque me da un error después de cierto tiempo que el programa esta corriendo y Firefox por alguna razón me consume mucha memoria.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que esa ventana te la saca la página que estás visitando, y no Safari. ¿Te aseguras de no tenerla inactiva demasiado tiempo? ¿O será quizás que aunque interactúes con la página ésta "no se entera" por culpa de que Safari, via Selenium, no le pasa los eventos correctamente?

Comment: Perdón por tardar en contestar. Esa ventana sale independientemente de cual sea la página que sé visite. Ahorita he estado usando Chrome para unas pruebas, creo que Safiri a veces es un poco inestable con Selenium.